# How to know TFS version without access the TFS server?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am the TFS admin, but I don't have permission access the TFS server, how to I use visual studio 2015 or through web portal get the TFS version?
I can run dos command like

```
tf info
tf destroy
```

Regards,
Tony

Comment: `I am the TFS admin, but I don't have permission access the TFS server` - Well that seems like it would make your job pretty hard to do.

Comment: System admin and network admin manage the servers, and i don't have permission access the server room and also no permission to connect remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I open the web portal and go Help, after I click the About, I got information

```
About Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 14.102.25423.0

© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I think that is my TFS version.

Comment: That's correct. That should be TFS 2015.3 which means that you should install Update 4 or, better, upgrade to a more recent version.